# APNS - PHP Codeigniter push notification Badge not increasing iOS7

Tags: php, codeigniter, push-notification, apple-push-notifications, apns-php

I have been working in an iOS project with APNS (Apple Push Notification service) + PHP, Codeigniter library. But currently I am stuck with an issue – Badge count increment is not reflecting in mobile. I had searched enough google links, so dont send some links. I need an exact solution, can anyone help me as I am having a short timeline upfront?

```
send_push_notification($device_token,$message,$badge,$sound='default');
```

Comment: Did you try this?
https://github.com/chrisnharvey/CodeIgniter-iOS-Push-Notifications

Comment: You will get sloutions from here https://code.google.com/p/apns-php/wiki/License . Just integrate this library in to codeigniter .. It will work in iOS7 and iOS8 ... We can easily use Set_badge($badge) . $badge count must be get from DB

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will get sloutions from here  https://code.google.com/p/apns-php/wiki/License . Just integrate this library in to codeigniter .. Badge Counter will work in iOS7 and iOS8 ... We can easily use Set_badge($badge) . $badge count must be get from DB